# Why can't iptables see rules added using firewalld?

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

I have a CentOS7 machine, and I use firewalld as my firewall. Recently I added a few rules using `firewall-cmd`:

```
# Removing DOCKER-USER CHAIN (it won't exist at first)
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-chain ipv4 filter DOCKER-USER

# Flush rules from DOCKER-USER chain (again, these won't exist at first; firewalld seems to remember these even if the chain is gone)
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-rules ipv4 filter DOCKER-USER

# Add the DOCKER-USER chain to firewalld
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-chain ipv4 filter DOCKER-USER

# Add rules (see comments for details)
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter DOCKER-USER 0 -j REJECT -i eth0 -dport 27017
```

I rebooted and checked the `direct.xml` file; the rules are there. I check using firewall-cmd and see the chain and the rules:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter DOCKER-USER
0 -j REJECT -i eth0 -dport 27017
```

And yet, if I do a `iptables -nvL`, I don't see that chain anywhere:

```
iptables -nvL |grep DOCKER
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
```

And if I use `firewall-cmd`, I don't see the chains that appear using `iptables` either. For example, I do have a `f2b-sshd` chain created by fail2ban, and yet this returns nothing:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter f2b-sshd
```

What's going on? I had the idea that both iptables and firewalld just manipulated the underlying kernel, that they were just different interfaces for the same thing. Why can't one see the rules created by the other? And which ones prevail?

Comment: I'm no expert but I believe you can't have both, if you have firewalld, iptables is disabled and visa-versa. I could be wrong though.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, when adding a rule using --permanent it isn't actually active until you do firewall-cmd --reload which replaces runtime rules with your permanent rules.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I looked at the error logs.

```
firewalld[573]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: The -t option (seen in line 3) cannot be used in iptables-restore.
```

So that's why the rules didn't show up: they weren't being applied.

Now the question becomes: how to use firewalld to add rules to a given table or chain...

Comment: https://firewalld.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use iptables with firewalld, you will need to make sure that the firewalld.conf file is configured for FirewallBackend=iptables. It's default is nftables but if you set it to iptables and restart firewalld, you will be able to use iptables as we're all used to.